# iPhone 6 dropped on my sink no cracks but broken inside

Tags: iphone, apple-store, warranty

When I dropped my iPhone on the sink it didn't crack but it did break inside.

I can't use my iPhone. I can turn it on but it isn't fully functional. There are lines and white blocks on the screen.

I am wondering, if I have a warranty, can I get it repaired for free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch! There's two ways you can possibly save your phone here.

Accidental damage is covered under [AppleCare+](https://www.apple.com/support/products/iphone.html), which is a separate purchase. If you don't know you have this, you probably don't.

(But try calling Apple support at 800-275-2273 and give them the serial number)

You may also have insurance through your carrier (commonly called Asurion, TEC, or something else similar), if you have this, it's a separate line item on your phone bill.

If not, I'm afraid you're out of luck :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can turn it on just fine, then the processor IS working, believe it or not.

If your screen is not showing any content, then your screen is broken. Consider replacing that.

If your phone is unable to process touch events, replace the phone's digitizer.

Best of luck! :)